# O SO está sob ataque?

Tags: suporte, status-pronto

Estava percebendo um lag faz uns 10 minutos, e agora a pouco vi esta página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então entrando no [StatusStackExchange](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) está a mensagem:

> ## We are currently mitigating an attack. Standby for updates.

WTF?

Comment: Não, deve ser manutençao programada

Comment: Mas e a mensagem no StatusStack? @rray

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309168/1342547, não tinha visto a segunda parte, e ta bem lento o site agora.

Comment: Agora apareceu outra: `We are deploying a mitigation shortly, hang on.`.

Comment: Parece que passou: [We are back online and monitoring all systems](https://twitter.com/StackStatus).

Comment: Isso é mais comum do que você imagina.

Comment: Assustador. Mas emocionante. rsrs

Comment: @rray A página do seu link foi deletada. Alguém que tem 10000 pontos de reputação no metão pode explicar o que era?

Comment: @victor sta, a ultima vez tava em -10

Comment: @rray Isso era alguma mensagem que os atacantes deixaram ou algo assim?

Comment: @VictorStafusa estava em -13 quando foi tirado do ar. Era um cara falando que o certo era o SO passar o link do atacante pra ele atacar de volta... algo assim, essas horas o google tradutor não me ajuda muito :/ Mas foi muito rápido, achei que ia rolar uma debate ali, mas nem, apagaram mesmo. Eu tinha até feito uma edição na pergunta pra referenciar, mas depois que apagaram tirei...

Comment: Não, nada a ver, era um user com 22k de rep falando mais ou menos isso que eu disse acima....

Comment: @bfavaretto você tem acesso lá?

Comment: A última vez [estava assim](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrk4D.jpg) @VictorStafusa

Comment: @rray Não mudou muito, levou mais 4 negativos e uns 2 comentários antes de apagarem.

Comment: @bfavaretto, valeu \o